# Not Able to Make HTTPConnection

Tags: android

I'm new to android development n i'm trying to make HTTPConnection.
I make two files one is ParsingActivity.java(Main Activity File)and other one is XMLParser.java (For setting up the HTTPRClient Request).

ParserActivity.java

```
package ok.done;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class ParsingActivity extends Activity {

    String URL = "http://api.androidhive.info/pizza/?format=xml";
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        System.out.println("t1==========>"+URL);


        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL);

        System.out.println("t2==========>"+xml);
    }
}
```

XMLParsing.java

```
package ok.done;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

public class XMLParser {

    // constructor
    public XMLParser() {

    }

    public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
        String xml = null;

        System.out.println("t3==========>"+xml);
        System.out.println("t4==========>"+url);

        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            System.out.println("t5==========>"+url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

            System.out.println("t6==========>"+xml);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // return XML
        return xml;
    }

}
```

I also add the permission in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ok.done"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".ParsingActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>


</manifest>
```

And the LogCat result for my System.out.println are

for t1==========>http://api.androidhive.info/pizza/?format=xml
    t3==========>null
    t4==========>http://api.androidhive.info/pizza/?format=xml
    t5==========>null
    t6==========>null
    t2==========>null

but if everything is perfect in my this simple code thein for the result of t6,t2 is the xml file description.

Any one plz suggest me what should I do or any other links which will be helpful for me for creating XML parsing type application.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: are you want to post someone or just xmlparser?

Comment: actually i have to parse this xml but for that i have to get the result from getXmlFromUrl but it returned null that's not right if it gives me result then i'll be able to go further...

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the http server gives a valid xml after firing. To make sure fire the url on web browser, if server gives the xml, you will get the xml content.